# How can I charge customers on my website a monthly payment with Google Pay?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, google-pay

I have a website where users can post an ad.

And once in a month I charge them for the amount of clicks clicked on their ad.

Now I want to charge them once in a month through the Google Pay service, is it possible?

** From the searches I did I realized that PayPal has such an option to create a subscription and charge the user once in a month. But I did not find a similar option in Google Pay **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this FAQ](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/faq#recurring-billing), yes, it's supported, but you need to be in touch with Google:

> We also support recurring billing with variable amounts. For example, monthly phone bills for mobile carriers are supported. To get more information, merchants must contact their payment gateway representative.

Comment: Not with Google but with the payment gateway.